# Prove that $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)\geq 8$.

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Let $x, y, z$ be positive integers,  such that $\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y}+ \frac{1}{z} \leq 1$. Find $\inf_{x, y, z} (x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$.

After a few trials,  I'd say the answer is $8$, but I can't prove it. Using Am-GM I wasn't even able to prove the $\inf$ was $\geq 8$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. He is lokking for an inf

Comment: The inequality in the title needed to be reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$. We get 
$$xyz-(xy+yz+xz)+(x+y+z)-1.\tag{1}$$

By the constraint $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\le 1$, the sum of the first two terms in (1) is $\ge 0$.

So we want to show that $x+y+z\ge 9$. This follows from the Arithmetic Mean Harmonic Mean Inequality. We have equality only at $x=y=z=3$.

Comment: I agree. So this generalizes to positive reals. You should add that (3,3,3) achieves the inf.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{1}{x}=a, \frac{1}{y}=b, \frac{1}{z}=c$. Then $a+b+c\le 1$. WOLOG, let us suppose $a+b+c=1$. We need to show that

$$
\Pi \frac{a+b}{c} \ge 8
$$

Now you can use Am-GM.

Answer (score 1):

the product is monotonically increasing in each variable. so can't we consider triples starting with $(1,1,1)$ eliminating families of triples violating the reciprocal sum on the way?

wlog $x \leq y \leq z$.

this way we have $x,y,z > 1$, $x = 2 \rightarrow y \geq 3, z \geq 4$, $x = 2 \land y = 3 \rightarrow z \geq 6$, $x = 2 \land y = 4 \rightarrow z \geq 4$, and therefore minimal elements $\{(2,3,6),(2,4,4),(3,3,3)\}$ for the set of valid triples $(x, y, z)$ and the partial order $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \leq_{t} (x_1,y_1,z_1) \equiv x_0 \leq x_1 \land y_0 \leq y_1 \land z_0 \leq z_1 $.

$(2-1)(3-1)(6-1) = 10, (2-1)(4-1)(4-1) = 9, (3-1)(3-1)(3-1) = 8$ which completes the proof.